# Physics issue unity 3d

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, physics

My unity game is a spring and when you hold the space key the spring moves back. When you release the space bar the spring releases depending on the amount of torque built up when holding down space bar.

When it is released the spring just overlaps inside the sphere I need the ball to move forward faster or slower depending on the amount of power in the Power variable.

I cannot use Rigidbody.Addforce as the spring needs to cause the ball to move.

### Script Notes:

-> If the spring is fully out (released) it should have a value of -2 If it is held in to its maximum torque it should have an x axis value of -2.2

---

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class SpringMechanics : MonoBehaviour {

public bool SpringIn;
public float Power;
public bool SpringReleased;
void Update()
{
    // IF THE SPRINGS X POSITION IS AT -2 OR ABOVE THAT VALUE IT WILL MARK THE SPRING IN VARIBALE AS TRUE

    if (transform.position.x >=-0.5f)
    {
        SpringIn = false;

    }
    else
    {
        SpringIn = true;
    }

    //CHECKS IF MOUSE SPACE BUTTON IS DOWN AND IF SO MOVES SPRING IN

    if (Input.GetKey (KeyCode.Space) && transform.position.x <= 2.3) {
                    Debug.Log ("Spring Being Compressed");

                    // Moves Spring Backwards when space key is down

        //rigidbody.velocity = new Vector3(rigidbody.velocity.x - 0.05f * Time.deltaTime,rigidbody.velocity.y,rigidbody.velocity.z);
                            transform.position = (new Vector3 (transform.position.x - 0.05f * Time.deltaTime, transform.position.y, transform.position.z));
                            // Adds 3 Units Of Power Every Second While Key Is Down
                            Power += 2 * Time.deltaTime;

            }
    //Releases Ball When Space Bar Is Up After Being Down

    if (Input.GetKeyUp (KeyCode.Space))
    {
        SpringReleased = true;
    }

    if (SpringReleased == true) 
    {
        FireBall();

    }
}

//When Firing Ball Executer Below Function
void FireBall()
{
    if (transform.position.x <= -2){
        rigidbody.velocity = new Vector3(rigidbody.velocity.x + Power * Time.deltaTime,rigidbody.velocity.y,rigidbody.velocity.z);
        //transform.position = (new Vector3 (transform.position.x + Power * Time.deltaTime, transform.position.y, transform.position.z));
        transform.position = (new Vector3 (-2, transform.position.y, transform.position.z));

        if (transform.position.x >= -2 && SpringReleased == true){
            SpringReleased=false;
            Power = 0;
            rigidbody.velocity = new Vector3(0,0,0);
            Debug.Log ("Reset Spring");

            }
        }   
    }
}
```

How can I make it be hit forward towards the right using the spring depending on the value of of the power variable?

Comment: Anyone know what I can do here?

Comment: Depends, what is your question?

Comment: @TimCastelijns My unity game is a spring and when you hold the space key the spring moves back. When you release the space bar the spring releases depending on the amount of torque built up when holding down space bar.

When it is released the spring just overlaps inside the sphere I need the ball to move forward faster or slower depending on the amount of power in the Power variable.

I cannot use Rigidbody.Addforce as the spring needs to cause the ball to move.

Comment: I read that part, but I see no question in there

Comment: @TimCastelijns How can I make it be hit foreward towards the right using the sprong depending on the value of of the power variabe.

Answer (score 0):

Apply the force to the spring (or some part of the spring, like a separate mesh at the top) instead and the physics engine should do the rest.

Comment: The force is applied to the spring because the script is attached to it

Comment: And I fixed it a bit now it just packs a tiny punch to the ball not very hard at all.